# ASP.Net MVC LabelFor not working on postback or page load

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, radio-button

I am working with ASP.Net MVC and wanting to use radio buttons to get a bool value back of true or false

I have tried HTML helpers and no joy so resorted to straight html like so.

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.ReleaseAsSoonAsPossible, true, Model.ReleaseAsSoonAsPossible ? (object) new {@checked = "checked", id = "ReleaseAsSoonAsPossibleTrue"} : "")<label For="ReleaseAsSoonAsPossibleTrue" class="control-label">Release as soon as possible</label>
<br/>
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.ReleaseAsSoonAsPossible, false, !Model.ReleaseAsSoonAsPossible ? (object) new {@checked = "checked", id = "ReleaseAsSoonAsPossible"} : "")<label For="ReleaseAsSoonAsPossible" class="control-label">Schedule release on: </label>
```

The page is initially loaded in as a partial on the click of a button and the label for click works as expected and selects the radio button accordingly, however, if a record exists for the user on page load or subsequent postback clicking the label does not work.

I have looked in the console and and monitored the click \ change event and there are 6 events that are fired off, but no actual state change of the radio button.

I would be grateful for any suggestions on how to fix this as I am stuck scratching my head at the moment.

Comment: Not related, but remove the `@checked = "checked"` code (the `checked` attribute is set by the method based on the value of `ReleaseAsSoonAsPossible`)

Comment: And do you mean that you are adding multiple instance of that same partial (which means you have invalid html because of duplicate `id` attributes)

Comment: @StephenMuecke ill try removing the checked, but no, there is only ever one instance of this on the page

Comment: You question is a bit confusing - you start by saying _so resorted to straight html like so_ but then show the `HtmlHelper` methods. You need to give us a bit more information, including the model, and controller methods, and any scripts

Comment: the straight html is for the lable, rather than using the @Html.LabelFor(....)